# sending 4 bytes of HEX on linux commandline

Tags: bash, shell, socketcan

I have a command

`for i in {1..9} ; do cansend slcan0 "7e0#02090"$i"0000000000"`

How can I send the same command but for $i send 4 bytes of HEX instead. Sort of like a brute force ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`printf` utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) and `%04x` as a format specifier (`0` pad, `4` characters, format as he`x`):

```sh
for i in {1..9}; do
  command=$(printf "7e0#02090%04x0000000000" $i)
  echo cansend slcan0 "$command"  # remove `echo` here :)
done
```

prints out

```
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000010000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000020000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000030000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000040000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000050000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000060000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000070000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000080000000000
cansend slcan0 7e0#0209000090000000000
```

Comment: ok thanks, but thats only 1 byte of hex ? so i would just do %04%04%04%040000000 ?

Comment: `%04x%04x%04x%04x` maybe, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use brace expansion to generate a list of all 4-byte hex code sequences (`00000000`, `00000001`, `00000002`, …, `FFFFFFFF`).

`{{0..9},{A..F}}` generates the list `0 1 2 … F`.
`{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}` generates the list `00 0 02 … FF`.
And so on.
For 4 bytes you have to repeat `{{0..9},{A..F}}` 8 times as every byte has two hex digits.

```
for i in {{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}; do
   cansend slcan0 "7e0#02090${i}0000000000"
done
```

While this approach might be viable for two or three digits I would strongly advise against using it in this case. Above script is not readable and very slow.

The next better thing in bash would be …

```
bytes=4
((max=2**(bytes*8)-1))
for ((i=0; i<max; i++)); do
   printf -v hex %08x "$i"
   cansend slcan0 "7e0#02090${hex}0000000000"
done
```

… but please keep in mind that this will be *magnitudes* slower than sending sequences from a (for instance) python program which doesn't have to start a new process each time you want to send something to slccan0.

Comment: ok i appreciate the guidance. i am trying to achieve this in a much more efficient manner. i wasnt getting the connection to the ECU using slcan and python. but if you can offer any guidance on how to do it i am happy to try it

Comment: @FaheemAdam I cannot help you further than this. I have no idea what an ECU or any of that stuff is. I just thought, that maybe `cansend` offers a library interface to do the same thing from inside a regular program which would be faster than calling `cansend` over and over again from a bash script.